# "bash: cd: .config/: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line

I get this error when typing `cd .config/`:

```
bash: cd: .config/: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: If you're new to Linux in general, a good introduction to the Terminal (bash-shell) can be had by browsing through the "bash guides" at www.tldp.org - they're a bit old, but still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The `~/.config` directory is directly in your home directory, and not under `~/Desktop`.

Type this to make it work:

```
cd ~/.config
```

... where `~` is your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

@ArturMeinild is right.

If you type the `pwd` command you can see "present working directory" - where you are. And you can also see it in  the "prompt" - the string before the `$` in your screenshot. You current directory is `~/Desktop`, which is equivalent to `$HOME/akargar`, which typically means `/home/akargar/Desktop`, but `$HOME` doesn't have to be there, it could be in other places too. So when you write `cd .config`, you're asking to change to the sub-directory `.config` *of the current directory* - `/home/akargar/Desktop/.config`, which doesn't exist. But `~/.config` in your `$HOME` directory almost certainly exists.